# Dapper query slow with DateTime type parameter?

Tags: oracle, dapper, parameterized

eg.1

```
string sql="select * from A where time>=:begin_time and time<=:end_time";

DateTime bt = new DateTime(2013, 04, 19);
DateTime et = new DateTime(2013, 04, 20, 15, 0, 0);
conn.Query<Object>(sql,new {begin_time=bt,end_time=et}).ToList()
```

the query is slow, the time is 00:00:02.2142132

---

eg.2

```
string sql="select * from A where time>=to_date(:begin_time,'yyyy-mm-dd      hh24:mi:ss') and time<to_date=(:end_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";

conn.Query<Object>(sql,new {begin_time="2013-04-19 0:00:00",end_time="2013-04-20 15:00:00"}).ToList()
```

the query is fast, the time is 00:00:00.4604229

---

The following is a new test case. all test record count is 39 from database.

group1: Use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

test1: 00:00:01.9456767. use dapper and datetime is datetime type(eg1. :begin_time)

test2: 00:00:00.6667549. use dapper and datetime is string type(eg2. to_date(:begin_time,format) )

test3: 00:00:01.8552286. use ado.net/OracleCommand/OracleDataAdapter and datetime is datetime type(eg1. :begin_time)

test4: 00:00:00.0592419. use ado.net/OracleCommand/OracleDataAdapter and datetime is string type(eg2. to_date(:begin_time,format))

---

group2: Use System.Data.OracleClient

test5: 00:00:00.0184799. use dapper and datetime is datetime type(eg1. :begin_time)

test6: 00:00:00.1158088. use dapper and datetime is string type(eg2. to_date(:begin_time,format) )

test7: 00:00:00.0193022. use ado.net/OracleCommand/OracleDataAdapter and datetime is datetime type(eg1. :begin_time)

test8: 00:00:00.0185583. use ado.net/OracleCommand/OracleDataAdapter and datetime is string type(eg2. to_date(:begin_time,format))

I found if use System.Data.OracleClient two ways are fast. only use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, the eg1 is sill slow and eg2 is fast.

May be the cause of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Comment: Is that consistent behavior?  Or are you potentially seeing the effects of caching when you run the second query?  Are you seeing a different plan for the two queries?

Comment: Caching is false, and eg.1 is always slow,eg.2 is always is fast.

Comment: BTW，my database is oracle.

Comment: Are you getting different plans for the two queries?

Comment: the eg.2 plan is :![Valid XHTML](http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/005X3q9sjw1ep43qqcfmkj30vh04e766.jpg).. the ge1 plan I can't get.

Comment: I just test mssql , the eg.1 and eg.2 are fast, only  eg.1 is slow on oracle db.

Comment: If you have a query plan, please edit your post to include it.  I can't follow the link you posted in comments.

Comment: If you use raw ADO.NET (remove dapper from the equation): does it continue to be slow one way (via typed) and fast the other (as a string) ?

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is faster than Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,because oci.dll?

Answer (score 5):

I've been having a similar problem with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, and I've discovered that `DateTime` parameters are converted to `Timestamp` inside the query. If your time column is a `Date` instead of a `Timestamp`, Oracle will implicitly convert it to a `Timestamp`, and it won't be able to use any indexes on that column.

Try rewriting your query to be:

```
select * from A where time>=cast(:begin_time as date) and time<=:cast(end_time as date)
```

And see if that improves performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), DbType.Date);
```

Because Dapper default set typeof(DateTime) equal DbType.DateTime,
but DbType.DateTime default equal OracleDbType.TimeStamp,
so can set DbType.Date mapping OracleDbType.Date.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me!
Just remember to apply it at the beginning of the program. It seems it is not possible to add the TypeMap after a query to db.
Thanks Walter!

Comment: What is the code to add, is it the first line in your post or the last line. This answer is quite hard to actually understand what you mean?